# TypeError: n is not a function in SPFx component

Tags: react-hooks, spfx

In a SPFx (1.12.1 or 1.13.0) React webpart ,I have an Array of objects in the state, that I show in a parent component with:

```
{upfiles.map((file, i) => {
               return (<FileActionComponent i={i} setcurrentMessage={setcurrentMessage} />);
   })}
```

Inside the "FileActionComponent" component, I have  buttons to change the array.
When the change is to an item, it works fine but when the change is to remove the item from the array, I get the following error the number of times as the length of the array:

```
TypeError: n is not a function
    at https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70:90216
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70:5230)
    at Bi (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70:50948)
    at is (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70:90138)
    at cs (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70:92705)
    at uc (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70:105747)
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70:5230)
    at Bi (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70:50948)
```

If I remove an item from outside of the "FileActionComponent" component, it works fine but it is not the desired UX.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, what about removing it from the outside of the "FileActionComponent"? Usually you modify the collection in the component which owns it (and notify that component to moify it with "events" raised in a child component). The error message is unfortunately not very informative, you may consider enabling sourcemaps to get understandable errors.

Comment: I did it and that part works now. but I have a root component and 2 child components which I show if a number matches   {(requestStep === 2) && ... but when the first child component changes the number for the other one to show, I get the same error again.  I thought this was valid practice.